# Nuances when using とはいうものの

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, word-usage

I'm studying とはいうものの when used after a full stop in this way.

"......。とはいうものの、......。"

According to the very few examples I could find about this grammar pattern used in this way (after a full stop, not after a clause), it seems to mean "however". However, I don't know very well the nuances of it as well as when I can use it and when not.

Would "___。とはいうものの" be always interchangeable with other conjunctions that also mean "however" like しかし for example? If not, could you please give me an example where I can see the difference in usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [とはいうものの](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE/) is close to English *that said* (or maybe just sometimes). It is usually followed by something that adds reservations to the antecedent or things that are unexpected.

しかし is more simple *but*.

---

Examples:

- 4月だ。しかしまだ寒い。It is April, but it is still cold.
- 4月だ。とはいうもののまだ寒い。

Both are fine (probably the latter sounds more natural).

- 彼は働き者だ。しかし彼の弟は怠け者だ。He is hard-working, but his brother is lazy.

Here しかし indicates the contrast between him and his brother, and とはいうものの cannot be used.

- 駅は近い。とはいうものの歩いて30分はかかる。 The station is near. Yet it is a 30 minute walk.

Here しかし may be not entirely impossible, but sounds much less natural. It gives a reservation to the *near*. (The first sentence in this paragraph may translate to: とはいうものの、ここで「しかし」が使えないわけではない)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I understand better とはいうものの. :)